# LEFT JOIN / IS NULL not working as expected -to select only row which is not in another table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to select rows which is not in another table. Here I have used **LEFT JOIN** with **IS NULL**, but not getting expected result. It works only one for table, but not in another table.

Mainly I Can't manage the relation between four tables. `fee` - that includes fee categories) and `fee_tm` - includes lists of month to pay fee), `cls_fee` - fee criteria of each classes) and `invoice` - contains information about paid fee).

And in result I am trying to show student lists who haven't paid, or those students records which is not in `invoice` table.

**Mysql**

```
SELECT
    fee_tm.id AS ftm_d,
    fee.id AS f_id,
    fee_tm.en_ttl AS f_tm,
    fee.en_ttl AS fee,
    cls_fee.fee AS f_mnt
FROM
    fee
LEFT JOIN
    fee_tm ON fee_tm.year = fee.year
LEFT JOIN
    cls_fee ON cls_fee.fee_id = fee.id
LEFT JOIN
    student ON student.cls = cls_fee.c_id AND student.sec = cls_fee.s_id
LEFT JOIN
    invoice ON invoice.stu_id = student.id AND invoice.fee_id = fee.id AND invoice.ftm_id = fee_tm.id
WHERE
    student.id =1 AND invoice.ftm_id is NULL AND invoice.fee_id is NULL
```

**Current Result**

```
ftm_d   |   f_id    |   f_tm    |   fee     |   f_mnt
=====================================================
2       |   1       |   Feb     |   Annual  |   1000
2       |   2       |   Feb     |   Monthly |   560
```

**Expected Result**

```
ftm_d   |   f_id    |   f_tm    |   fee     |   f_mnt
=====================================================
2       |   2       |   Feb     |   Monthly |   560
```

My result is checking only `f_tm` column, so in my current result month `Jan` is filtered, but it has to check the `fee` column also and the `Annual` row has to be filtered.

So, we can know the students who haven't paid their fee. If the record is found in `invoice` table, then this fee category should be filtered in result.

**Database Structure**

**Student**

```
id  |   en_ttl  |   cls |   sec |   year
========================================
1   |   John    |   1   |   1   |   1
```

**cls**

```
id  |   en_ttl  |   year
========================
1   |   One     |   1
```

**sec**

```
id  |   en_ttl  |   year
========================
1   |   A       |   1
```

**fee**

```
id  |   en_ttl  |   year
========================
1   |   Annual  |   1
2   |   Monthly |   1
3   |   Library |   1
```

**fee_tm**

```
id  |   en_ttl  |   year
========================
1   |   Jan     |   1
2   |   Feb     |   1
```

**cls_fee**

```
id  |   c_id    |   s_id    |   fee_id  |   fee
===============================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   1       |   1000
2   |   1       |   1       |   2       |   560
```

**invoice**

```
id  |   stu_id  |   fee_id  |   ftm_id
======================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   1
```

DDL Statements of tables

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
 `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `en_ttl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `cls` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `sec` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `cls` (
 `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `en_ttl` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sec` (
 `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `en_ttl` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `fee` (
 `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `en_ttl` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `fee_tm` (
 `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `en_ttl` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `cls_fee` (
 `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `c_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `s_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `fee_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `fee` int(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `fee` (`c_id`,`s_id`,`fee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
 `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `stu_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `fee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ftm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Do you mean `cls_fee.fee AS f_mnt`?

Comment: @Nick, sorry for that, I've edited recently

Comment: Why not just add `fee.en_ttl = 'Monthly'` to your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: If you say what you are trying to achieve rather than what you did with your query(like, i am trying to get students who have not paid their fee etc.,) , it would be easy for people to help.

Comment: @Nick, Actually `fee` is filled dynamically and can be more, I've showed limited here, only for less code

Comment: @Vishal.R, you are right but while asking previous question, I found it has been recommended to talk with exact problem that you are facing rather then being subjective.

Comment: @AnandHmt you have the find the right balance. Giving us all the data you are working with is great, but it's really not possible to figure out what you are trying to achieve just by looking at your expected results. So if you could put that in plain english (e.g. I'm trying to find monthly fees which haven't been invoiced) you will have a much better chance of getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Nick, Appreciated.. just edited the question.

Comment: If I understand your datamodel correctly, your class has the following fees (for year 1, but you do not use that year in every join, so it won't work if you have more years): an annual fee of 1000 and a monthly fee of 560, that is, up to now, due for Jan and Feb, so 3 fees in total. You have 1 invoice for the monthly fee for Jan. Your query seems to correctly identify the 3-1=2 fees without matching invoices. As Nick and Vishal have said: if you explain (in words) that you don't want the annual fee, it would be clearer than letting us guess by the expected result that you do not want it.

Answer (score 0):

use studentid=1 in on cluase

```
    SELECT
    fee_tm.id AS ftm_d,
    fee.id AS f_id,
    fee_tm.en_ttl AS f_tm,
    fee.en_ttl AS fee,
    cls_fee.fee AS f_mnt
    FROM
    fee
inner JOIN
    fee_tm ON fee_tm.year = fee.year and fee.id=fee_tm.id inner join cls_fee on cls_fee.fee_id = fee.id
    LEFT JOIN
    student ON student.cls = cls_fee.c_id AND student.sec = cls_fee.s_id
    left join invoice  ON invoice.stu_id = student.id AND invoice.fee_id = fee.id AND invoice.ftm_id = fee_tm.id and student.id=1
    where invoice.fee_id is null
```

Comment: still same result

Comment: can you please provider ddl statement of your table structure

Comment: And maybe also add  `fee.en_ttl = 'monthly'` to the relevamt on

Comment: @fa06, Thanks, you mean `ddl` statement of every tables.

Comment: @AnandHmt, yes for every table

Comment: @fa06, please see updated question, I've posted **ddl** statement

Comment: @AnandHmt, modified my answer, you can check now